# How to clear the brush (d3) after selection (after the `end` listener callback function)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 brush as a zoom - to allow me to choose the time range to display from the bigger time range chart.

Therefore this selection:
[image]

Should result in the similar chart but for the time range 2004-2012. And that works fine. The issue is that the brush is not cleared and its values don't make any sense anymore:
[image]

But I don't know how to clear the brush in my code. Here it is:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const brush = brushX().extent([[0, 0], [innerWidth, innerHeight]]);
    brush(select(brushRef.current));
    brush.on('end', (e) => {
        decodeSelection(e.selection);
    });
    const decodeSelection = (brushExtent) => {
        if (brushExtent) {
            let selectedTimeValues = brushExtent.map(xScale.invert);
            let years = selectedTimeValues.map(date => date.getFullYear());
            onBrush(years);
        } else {
            onBrush(defaultTimeRange);
        }
    }
}, [innerWidth, innerHeight])
```

I am aware of `brush.clear()` function and `brush.move(null)` option but I don't have an access to `brush` from my decodeSelection selection function. I have tried passing it but it didn't work (to be honest I wasn't surprised, it felt weird to pass `brush` from brush listener) causing runtine `groups is undefined` error.

How is it supposed to be done?